# Не находится драйвер mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Хочу подключиться к mysql:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'login', 'passwd', 'dbname');
```

И PHP_7.0.3 выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\Apache24 ...

Расширение разкомментировл:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

dll на месте. Что еще нужно?

ОС Win 10. Версия MySQL 5.5.60

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81189/discussion-on-question-by------mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. В Apache 2.4 в конфиге, помимо строки LoadModule php7_module 'c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll' необходимо так же указать путь к php.ini - PHPIniDir "c:\php"